# Adding EventListeners to multiple Checkboxes - Android Studio/Java

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-checkbox

I'm trying to add event listeners to three checkboxes in my View. But when I test it on an android tablet, only one of the eventlisteners for the checkboxes works... Please help. (Note: I am very new to programming so a detailed explanation is appreciated. Thanks!)

Edit1:  The model class is basically in-charge of generating a REGEX string. The three checkboxes give the user an option to include/exclude numbers/digits/anchors to create the REGEX string. The code below is the controller in charge of adding eventlisteners to the 3 checkboxes, though I am not sure if I am doing it right.

EDIT2: Fixed it by adding final before CheckBox... no clue why it works :S

```
// a method in my controller
public void checkListener() {

  CheckBox dig = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dig);
  CheckBox blarg = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.blarg);
  CheckBox duff = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.duff);

  dig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
           model.setLetter(true); //setting a bool val in my model class
           newRegex(); // this method generates a regex string from the model class and outputs it into the View           }
       else {
           model.setLetter(false);
           newRegex(); // generates a regex string and updates the view
       }
  }

    blarg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
           model.setSomething(true); //setting a bool val in my model class
           newRegex();
       }
       else {
           model.setSomething(false);
           newRegex();
       }
  }

    duff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
           model.setAlpha(true);
           newRegex();
       }
         else {
           model.setAlpha(false); //setting a bool val in my model class
           newRegex();
       }
  }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "But when I deploy my app, only one of the checkboxes works...". can you be more specific about exactly what happens.

Comment: I test it out on an android tablet to make sure it runs. The model class is basically in-charge of generating a REGEX string. The three checkboxes give the user an option to include/exclude numbers/digits/anchors to create the REGEX string. When I click on one of the checkboxes, for ie the digits, it will only generate a regex string that contains anchors and letters. The problem is only one of the checkboxes update the regex string...

Comment: What do you mean by repeating the same statements?

Comment: sorry, it meant to have it set to false, please have a look again.